# Transpose into new columns; Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I could use some help in inventorying some online purchases.

I would like the information in column A to be separated into the following:
`Vendor name; item description; eBay item #; purchase price; shipping cost; purchase date`

example:
`ldean747; MEN'S WILLIAM BAY" "; 260725743398; 10.50; 0.00; 01/28/11`

I'm getting hung up because some of the products do not have shipping cost (which would be the second dollar amount you see in the picture).

Any easy way to do this rather than going through and copy paste, transpose on each purchase?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of challenges here

- dynamic data set format: 3 text fields followed by 1 or 2 numeric fields (vertically)
- multiple field seperators / delimiters across your data set

  - 1st field: '()''
  - 2nd field: '|'
  - 3rd field: ':'

You could now start to create formulas which extract the relevant parts of each field using functions like `=LEFT()`, `=MID()`, `=RIGHT()`, `=SEARCH()`, etc. which for some cases (3rd field) is pretty straightforward, for others can get a bit complex ...

Concretely - the fields can be identified as  following:

- if the cell above is numeric AND I am alpha THEN I am 1st field
- if the cell above is 1st field THEN I am 2nd field
- if the cell above is 2nd field THEN I am 3rd field
- if the cell above is 3rd field THEN I am product cost
- if the cell above is numeric AND I am numeric THEN I am shipping cost

numeric / alpha: `=TYPE()`, extracting substrings seperated by seperation characters is well covered here at SO

Alternatively you could start to write a VBA program that does the same job for you

meta code:

```
loop through all rows
    determine record type
    process record type
```

So give it a try and come back with more questions.